# Jquery e teclado em android e IOS

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, teclado, javascript-eventos

eu estou com dificuldade para capturar qual caractere o usuário pressionou quando usado smartphone com ANDROID/IPHONE. Uso o evento de keyup do jquery, mas a resposta é sempre undefined ou 229.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

O código que estou a usar:

```
$('#campo-valor').on('keyup', function(event) {
   console.log(event.which);
}
```

Comment: Adicione seu codigo pra conseguirmos entender melhor o problema.

Comment: No navegador desktop funciona normalmente o código, porém o mesmo código no android (Chrome - Moto G4 Plus) tem comportamento diferente não mostrando a tecla virtual que foi tocada. Já tentei eventos do tipo 'keydown' e 'keypress' e não funcionaram.